# trying to create java script logic

Tags: javascript

[image]

pls See image, im trying to create logic when
Zone_of_Interest__c==true and Authority_to_Proceed__c==false then show error msg, otherwise show the vf page

Comment: You look to be mixing Formula expression syntax with javascript syntax in some spots. I suggest you take a quick look at some Javascript tutorials (https://javascript.info/) to get the basics. You can then substitute a merge field into the javascript you write.

Comment: thanks, but please tell me how to give logic according to above mention condition.

Comment: put your code in writing without pasting image.

Comment: @AshishSoni please see [ask] and [answer] and revise your question.

Comment: Don't see why this question is off-topic so have voted for a reopen. Screen shot isn't the best choice but the question is specific and related to Salesforce.

Comment: I disagree this post should be reopened (yet). It does not contain any information about what is wrong with the current implementation, nor does it contain any *question*.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Good points. I now see that the OP has asked several questions and it seems has not chosen to heed the feedback on how to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look in the generated output - the result of combining the merge fields with the fixed text you supply - by using your browser's "View Source" to see what is going on. Then lots of Googling to make sure what is output is valid JavaScript. The result should look more like this:

```
if ({!BT_Job__c.Zone_of_Interest__c} && !{!BT_Job__c.Authority_to_Proceed__c}) {
    alert('Authority...');
} else {
    window.open('/apex...')
}
```